# Enum in a database

Tags: mysql, enums

I want to have an attribute in a table that I want to be able to update. What is the best way to implement it?

1. to use a data type "Enum"
2. to create a second table with the enum values and in the main table I will keep a enum_ID to the second table. And when I will want to add or update en enum value, I will just need to to update the specific row or delete or add?

Im using MySql

Comment: 2 sounds fine to me. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Second choice if better when want to update your attribute values. When your doing the update / insert of the new attribute,  `Id` of the attribute in the master table remains the same. You only need to do INSERT or UPDATE on your attributes table to add/change attributes.

If you go with the first choice and use `ENUM` data type, you will need to do `ALTER TABLE` every time you need to insert or update your attributes and you will need do an `UPDATE` in the main table for every `ENUM` value that changed.